# In python, how do I merge two text files when difference can be anywhere in the text?

Tags: python, file, text, merge, missing-data

Now I have a list of files and I want to combine files targeting a same serial number. Each file contains thousands of lines and each line has such a format: date, count, reading.

For example the first file:

```
"2019-12-23 00:00:00",1123,211685,34650.75,33225.69,...(hundreds of similar numbers)
 ...(hundreds of similar lines)
"2020-02-23 06:00:00",1372,211685,34651.22,33224.6,...
"2020-02-23 12:00:00",1373,211685,34650.34,33224.74,...
```

The 2nd file:

```
"2019-12-17 12:00:00",1101,211685,34649.3,33225.8...
 ...
"2020-02-15 00:00:00",1339,211685,34651.66,33225.32,...
"2020-02-15 06:00:00",1340,211685,34651.63,33225.19...
```

The problem is, the missing lines can be either in the beginning or at the end of the file. Initial 100 readings might be missing in one file while the other file may miss the latest 50 readings. I wonder what could be the best way to merge them? I can think of using "set", but I'm not sure if it is capable of adding missing lines in the middle of a file.

An example of completed lines:

```
"2019-12-17 12:00:00",1101,211685,34649.3,33225.8...
 ...
"2019-12-23 00:00:00",1123,211685,34650.75,33225.69,...
 ...
"2020-02-15 00:00:00",1339,211685,34651.66,33225.32,...
"2020-02-15 06:00:00",1340,211685,34651.63,33225.19...
 ...
"2020-02-23 06:00:00",1372,211685,34651.22,33224.6,...
"2020-02-23 12:00:00",1373,211685,34650.34,33224.74,...
```

Comment: Merge all files into a single one, remove duplicated lines and sort it  (by date seems to be easy) .

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you could put all the lines in a set(), and then sort the result if you really wish to keep that in order.

Comment: Do you want to maintain file order? `set` will scramble the lines but you can sort it when you are done and get everything in date order.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito  Thanks. Will python know the first 20 characters in each line representing date and can automatically sort them?

Comment: Dates can be expressed in many formats but it looks like yours will naturally sort on its string value, so no conversion is necessary.

Comment: @tdelaney File order is fine but the data in each file has to be in order eventually. It seems like I can use set within each merged file and then sort them by date.

Comment: @tdelaney I see thanks!

Comment: @ArthurV Please provide a couple of complete lines

Comment: @PedroLobito Completed lines provided. Thanks.

Comment: is `...` also part of the line? there are lines only with `...` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito `...` just means there are more similar data. Either similar numbers in a line or similar lines to the previous lines. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` doesn't maintain order but you can sort it later to get the output file you want. When a date string is written as year-month-day-hour-minute-second in UTC, then it can be sorted either highest to lowest or lowest to highest without any date conversion. Write it in American "June 31 2019 12:30 PM MST" and you'd need to convert to something sortable.

```
def merge_files(filenames, outfilename):
    rows = set()
    for filename in filenames:
        rows.update(open(filename))
    with open(outfilename, 'w') as fp:
        fp.writelines(sorted(rows))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint
files = ["merge_01.txt", "merge_02.txt"]
all_lines = []
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        all_lines += [x.strip() for x in f]

all_lines = list(set(all_lines))
all_lines.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date[1:20], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
pprint(all_lines)

with open("merge_all.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in all_lines:
        f.write(line+"\n")
```

---

```
['"2019-12-17 12:00:00",1101,211685,34649.3,33225.8',
 '"2019-12-23 00:00:00",1123,211685,34650.75,33225.69',
 '"2020-02-15 00:00:00",1339,211685,34651.66,33225.32',
 '"2020-02-15 06:00:00",1340,211685,34651.63,33225.19',
 '"2020-02-23 06:00:00",1372,211685,34651.22,33224.6',
 '"2020-02-23 12:00:00",1373,211685,34650.34,33224.74']
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/acd44583a1)

---

Pandas Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
files = ["merge_01.txt", "merge_02.txt"]
all_lines = []
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        all_lines += list([x.strip().replace("\"", "") for x in f])

df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split(",") for sub in all_lines], columns=["date", "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by='date').drop_duplicates()
df.to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/e7adf731e3)